# Will be ok or would be ok?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

Should I use *would* or *will*:

> 1. I think this solution would be ok.
> 2. I think this solution will be ok.

And if both can be used then what is the difference?

Comment: Also see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/will-would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first sentence, "I think this solution would be ok." conveys the message that the solution would be OK if it is implemented, while the second sentence, "I think this solution will be ok." conveys the message that it is already decided that that solution will be used.

In other words, number 1 sounds like you haven't decided yet, number 2 sounds like you already have decided.

"Would" is conditional. That means that we can use it when something may or may not happen.